# Trouble with setting colorkey

Tags: python, set, pygame

I am using python and I am trying to use the set_colorkey function from pygame.  I drew a simple stick figure in Microsoft Paint and I tried to set the colorkey to (255, 255, 255), but that doesn't work.  I used a pixel array to try to find out the actual color of the background and it returned -1.  I entered that as the colorkey, but it didn't work.  Can someone help me?

Comment: By the way, I used surface.get_at and it returned (255, 255, 255, 255).  I put that in as the colorkey and that didn't work either.

Comment: Never mind.  I got it.  I just forgot to convert the image to alpha

Comment: Never mind again.  It worked once and now it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unsure what you mean by "it didn't work", but from my own experience with color keys in pygame, setting the colorkey in the same line as loading the image will turn the image into a Nonetype object. This is because the set_colorkey method doesn't return the image, but only sets the colorkey. Make sure that you didn't write something like:

```
image = image.set_colorkey((255,255,255))
```

Additionally, writing set_colorkey(255,255,255) will cause an error, as the color parameter is one argument. That probably isn't your problem, because I suspect that "it didn't work" means that it blitted fine and without error, but did not get rid of the white that you want to make transparent.
Please provide more information, especially exactly what code you wrote to set the colorkey.
I hope I helped

Comment: When I put the image into the program, I first didn't use .convert() or .convert_alpha().  I then discovered that .convert_alpha() didn't work, but .convert() did.  By didn't work, I meant what you said about the proper color not being transparent.  Thanks for the help.